# Как добавить элемент VLC плеер в окно WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, vlc, activex

Добавил в элементы как компонент COM ActiveX plagin 1 / 2. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получаю сообщение[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И в итоге элементы неактивны, и я не могу перетащить их на окно WPF[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103768/embedding-a-vlc-player-into-a-wpf-application